# How to evenly line three p elements next to each other with flexbox

Tags: html, css

I am making three boxes next to each other. Each box has a image + header + text.
The first box contains a header with two words. When shrinking the browser the p content of box 2 and 3 are lined up higher than box 1.

The code which i used is:

```
<section id="boxes">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_1Color_Black.png" alt="html5 logo">
            <h3>HTML 5 Website</h3>
            <p>Curabitur porttitor metus odio, fringilla bibendum sem faucibus quis. C</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_1Color_Black.png" alt="html5 logo">
            <h3>Webbie</h3>
            <p>Curabitur porttitor metus odio, fringilla bibendum sem faucibus quis. C</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_1Color_Black.png" alt="html5 logo">
            <h3>Informatie</h3>
            <p>Curabitur porttitor metus odio, fringilla bibendum sem faucibus quis. C</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and the CSS:

```
#boxes .container {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 900px;
}

.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}


.box img {
    /*prevents image from being larger than it's container, but doesn't stretch it if it's smaller than the container*/
    /*if you had a 20x20px image, then it would not get stretched to match the container's width, but it would stay 20x20px. Whereas a 2000x2000px image would get scaled down to fit the container*/
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsbin.com/gudomuyora/edit?html,css,output

How to line up the top of the p elements within the 3 boxes evenly.

Comment: Did you try `text-align: center` for the `h3` and `p` tags?

Comment: does not work unfortunately

Comment: I get this: https://prnt.sc/ldlc6o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `justify-content: space-between` on `.box` to achieve this.

```css
#boxes .container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box img {
  max-width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.box h3 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box p {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="boxes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_1Color_Black.png" alt="html5 logo">
      <h3>HTML 5 Website</h3>
      <p>Curabitur porttitor metus odio, fringilla bibendum sem faucibus quis. C</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_1Color_Black.png" alt="html5 logo">
      <h3>Webbie</h3>
      <p>Curabitur porttitor metus odio, fringilla bibendum sem faucibus quis. C</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_1Color_Black.png" alt="html5 logo">
      <h3>Informatie</h3>
      <p>Curabitur porttitor metus odio, fringilla bibendum sem faucibus quis. C</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```